# Best way to generate a Texture.tres 's data by code available in the editor

Tags: godot

I want to have MyTexture.tres to generate the `Image`, and be able to visualise it both at run time and in the editor.

The goal is to have my own Texture type as a Resource file, that can be used like NoiseTexture, GradientTexture, etc, and to use it in the editor (on a Sprite, as a shader uniform...) and NOT to save any image data in project folder.

```
tool
extends ImageTexture

export var width := 100
export var height := 100


func _init():
    var image := Image.new()
    
    # ...
    # Generate the image data array
    # ...

    create_from_image(image)
```

Using the `tool` keyword, it works but the Image data is automatically saved into MyTexture.tres, so it break the best advantage that is to save a lot of space.

I assign a script to the .tres file trying inheriting both ImageTexture and ProxyTexture, but the result is the same once I call create_from_image() it saves it to the file.

```
[sub_resource type="Image" id=3]
data = {
"data": PoolByteArray( 127, 119, 254, 131, 131, 119, 25, ... ) <-----
"format": "RGBA8",
"height": 512,
"mipmaps": false,
"width": 512
}
```

May be I will try inheriting ViewportTexture but even if it works it seem wrong, that require accessing the SceneTree to instanciate the Viewport (from a Resource script), may be is there a clean way ?

Comment: @Theraot My question was not clear I edited it, may be what I am trying is not an expected behavior. That is the opposit to save any data, but to be able to treat a .tres file with my own generation logic like a saved NoiseTexture

Comment: One solution is to make a [Godot Module](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/cpp/custom_modules_in_cpp.html). I don't know if this can be done with [ReaourceFormatLoader](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resourceformatloader.html) and [ResourceFormatSaver](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resourceformatsaver.html) and I don't have the energy to look into it right now. And - of course - you could make a custom `Node` type that create a `Viewport` where it renders whatever you need, and from which you can get the `ViewportTexture`.

Comment: Thanks, I will explore these, but I first keep trying the way I started, it would be so useful to be able to generate dynamic textures quickly from GDScript and use it like builtins. I have some ideas to test, then I will test the Viewport hack, hopefully il will work